# Is there any format for videos like RAW format for photos?

Tags: video

Like the RAW format for photos which stores the exact image information that is of great use for post processing, are there any similar formats for video?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for DSLR's that could shoot video in RAW (which, btw, do not yet exist, although there are rumors that the next Canon 5D might have RAW video capability), or are you looking for any video camera that can shoot RAW video, such as Red One which is a professional video camera system that has RAW video capability (and also costs many thousands of dollars)?

Answer (score 9):

Yes there is but if you have to ask, you probably can't afford it :)

Digital video cameras for professional use can shoot in a RAW format with one file for each frame. The bandwidth required is enormous and requires fast hard drives or an output over a fiber-optic link. Pricing is several times that of a full-frame

Comment: True. And there's really no point unless you're going to print to 35mm for a cinema release.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually quite a number of cameras now available or announecd for 2012 that will use Raw video formats. Some of them are not even very expensive. 
REDCode: used by RED cinema cameras
ARRIRAW: used by Arri Alexa
CinemaDNG: Blackmagic Design, Digital Bolex, Ikonoskop, Weisscam, Kinoraw S35, S16, and S8p
Cineform: Kineraw

and more to come.